# Python Retain embedded /n during readline operations

Tags: python, arrays

**I have inherited a project, and I am completely new to Python**.  What I need to do is read records from a file that are in binary.  I need to read every byte to put in an bytearray for processing.  The input records can have embedded `/n` or any other binary value.  The program currently reads the file until it reaches the `/n` and stops reading. 
So a record that has 36 bytes will find the first `/n` say in position 4 and quit reading. 
I need to be able to read the `/n` for processing in the program. How do I get it to read all the bytes?

Here is the current file read line:

```
lcounter = 0
fline = open(inputFileName, 'rb')
    while True:
        DataRead = fline.readline().rstrip() # I don't want the last /n in each record
        if lcounter == 0:
           processLineOne()
        else:
           if lcounter == 1:
                aryDataRead = [DataRead]
           elif lcounter == 2:
                aryDataRead.append(DataRead)
            elif lcounter == 3:
                aryDataRead.append(DataRead)
                fline.close()
                break
        lcounter += 1
 ProcessDataRead()
```

Record 3 has 36 bytes, but only puts 3 in the array because byte 4 is `\n`. How do I keep the `\n`? Thanks

Comment: Stop treating binary files as though they were text?

Comment: They will end up being text when processed.

Comment: Could .readline().rstrip() the rstrip be the cause?

Comment: Use read(1) instead of readline. Check for whatever your record boundary marker is.

Comment: Removing the rstrip did not help.

Comment: Ok let me expand on the incoming file. The first record is not stored as binary, but integer, the next 10 to 20 records are stored in binary. The rest of the file is just text.  I can process the first record and most of the next 10 to 20 except when the record includes things like \n.  I can process all the records after the binary data fine.   I have no control over the incoming files so I need to process them as is.   Thanks

Comment: How is the length of each record expressed in the file format?

Comment: Not expressed, as any record can be 6 to 56,000 bytes long.  Minimum 6 but no real upper limit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out. 
This code reads all the bytes in the file
I can then do the processing I need to do.

```
fline = open(inputFileName, 'rb') 
low_bit_list = [byte for byte in bytearray(fline.read())]
print("low_bit_list", low_bit_list)
```

low_bit_list [178, 53, 203, **10**, 55, 48, 48, 13, 10]

notice that I do get the rest of the record after the /n (10) byte

Thanks for all the suggestions.